# What to do if I said two takbeers while standing up after my two sajda

Tags: salat, practical-islam

I was praying my four rakat Sunnah prayer after two farz rakat of Jummah
When I was in my third rakat after I finished my two sajda
I said takbeer and sat
And then I remembered I am in my third rakat
So I didn’t say Tashahud
And stood up saying takbeer again
Do I have to do sahu sijda or is my prayer valid?

Comment: Actually here are two points you said takbeer and sat and if I understood well said a 2nd takbeer and stood up. Further all this happened in a nafl (optional prayer).

Comment: Happened in sunnah prayer and rest u understood